# How come some buttons are not working in firefox for android?

Tags: android, html, firefox, button, input

how have you been?

Here, my new oddest problem showed up today. I have these magnificent inputs with type button, all around my web app, and this app is meant to run perfectly over mozilla firefox.  Everything went well until today, that I realized that some buttons are not working well.

They are rendered according CSS rules, and they are not disabled, cause the data is already validated, but when someone tries to submit the info, nothing happens, not even the normal behaviour of the button getting marked with the dotted line around it's inner text.

The workaround: to pinch zoom the button, and then I can click it, but it is really annoying to do, because some unexperienced users have told me it doesn't work, and I end up giving them an introductory course about a lot of functionalities of mozilla ff, they don't even care.

Please help!!!

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a mobile friendly layout for your web application. It sounds like your buttons are too small and FF is just not recognizing the screen press on top of the button.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will give feedback to let you know what happened!